# Limit domaing before full text search using pg_search in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search, pg-search

Is there to specify a limited table domain for being searched using pg_search ?

I'm thinking about using a number of chained calls to `where` on the ActiveRecord model before issuing a `pg_search` scoped search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version has the ability to operate on the results returned by `where` or `order` etc.

So you can perform a search such as: 
`YourModel.where(id: "some condition").search("query")`

Comment: Also, you can chain calls both before and after the search scope call and everything should just work.